# Yii2 and reactjs CORS filters gives Error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: ajax, reactjs, yii2, http-headers, cors

I am trying to use ajax request in reactJs to fetch a resource that require authentication from *Bearer Auth in Yii2*.

**Request Headers**

**Accept:** */*
**Accept-Encoding:** gzip, deflate, sdch, br
**Accept-Language:** en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
**Access-Control-Request-Headers:** authorization
**Access-Control-Request-Method:** GET
**Connection:** keep-alive
**Host:** localhost
**Origin:** http://localhost:8110
**Referer:** http://localhost:8110/
**User-Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36

**Response Headers**

**Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:** true
**Access-Control-Allow-Headers:** Authorization
**Access-Control-Allow-Methods:** GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS
**Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** http://localhost:8110
**Connection:** Keep-Alive
**Content-Length:** 150
**Content-Type:** application/json; charset=UTF-8
**Date:** Fri, 21 Apr 2017 10:36:27 GMT
**Keep-Alive:** timeout=5, max=99
**Server:** Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu)
**Www-Authenticate:** Bearer realm="api"

This is my behavior method in yii2 framework

```
public function behaviors()
  {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
        return [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
                    'only' => ['view', 'index', 'filters', 'slug', 'shortlist'],  // in a controller
                    // if in a module, use the following IDs for user actions
                    'formats' => [
                        'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                    ],
                ],
                'corsFilter' => [
                    'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                    'cors' => [
                        'Origin' => ['*'],
                        'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS'],
                        'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                        ],
                ],
                'authenticator' => [
                        'class' => \yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                        'except' => ['options'],
                ],
        ];
  }
```

I know this some issue related to *CORS* because the same request is working fine with Postman and cURL(from terminal) with the same token, reactjs and ajax showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is at:

```
'except' => ['options'],
```

Class "HttpBearerAuth" inherits [yii\base\ActionFilter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-actionfilter) which public property "$except" according to the documentation defines a "list of action IDs that this filter should not apply to". Not the http methods.
So the above will not except a preflight request from "authenticator", but to the actionOptions() which is not what you want.

What you should do is **avoid returning a 401 http error for an OPTIONS http request**(which causes your error), **and just return a 200 empty response**.
You could do this by adding:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    //your code

    if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
        parent::beforeAction($action);
        Yii::$app->getResponse()->getHeaders()->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        Yii::$app->end();
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Comment: Shows a blank page with 200 status and no response. No error made, moreover I dont have `beforeAction` defined in my Controller

Comment: Ok, I have updated it. Add the beforeAction method in your controller.

Comment: Now My all CORS headers are not working may be because first beforeAction is executing and there are no CORS present at that time.

Comment: Actually, you have to call parent::beforeAction() in order for the CORS headers to be added to the response. I  updated my answer to include this.